# Yii User Authentication via RESTful with JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, yii, restful-authentication

I want to be able to authenticate a user in Yii against a user table in a database on email and password. I can do this in Yii, but now i want to be able to authenticate the same user via RESTful with JSON format. Below is my Yii code for authentication, which is in the Yii defaut LoginForm model:

```
/**
 * Authenticates the password.
 * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
 */
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{

    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Incorrect email or password.');
    }

}

/**
 * Logs in the user using the given email and password in the model.
 * @return boolean whether login is successful
 */
public function login()
{

    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution - I am also in the same position as you

Answer (score 0):

This authentification based on Cookie/SESSION mechanism, so it will not work for API queries. I suggest you to use Query Authentication with additional signature parameters. See [this reference article](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html). In a nutshell, you should recieve user login and password hash, check them with db data, then return to client some randomly generated token, that will be used for signing all other queries (save this token to db and check it).